# Is it possible to embed a Python/Django app in a Java Web App?

Tags: java, django, tomcat, servlets, leveldb

I have a java web application running on Apache Tomcat and a django application. They both interact with the same database(levelDB).Since they are two different processes, they both can't interact with database at the same time. My preferred solution, is to have the django app embedded in the Java app(main application) so that interacting with the database can be synchronised.

Comment: You should consider switching to a db that can have multiple clients, say `redis`?